# How can I find the presentation of the compactification of a planar hyperelliptic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, compactification

A hyperelliptic curve is defined as the projective compactification of a planar curve of the form
$$
\textbf{Spec}\left( \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{(y^2 - \prod(x - a_i))} \right)
$$
Is there a general method for computing the compactifications of hyperelliptic curves? If so, how can I compute the corresponding projective scheme in terms of a graded coordinate ring?

If not, how can I find the compactification of these hyperelliptic curves?
$$
\begin{align*}
& y^2 - x(x-1)(x-3)(x-5)(x-7) \\
& y^2 - x(x-1)(x-2)
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: The first curve is a genus 2 hyperelliptic curve while taking the homogenization would return a genus 6 projective curve.

Comment: My mistake. I see what you want now. I think this is sort of subtle.

Comment: That's okay. I wonder if this is more of a MO question.

Comment: So I don't know how computable this is, but the easiest way I know of to get a smooth projective compactification (assuming your original curve $C_0$ is smooth of degree $d$) is to take the closure $\tilde{C}$ of $C_0$ under the embedding $$\begin{aligned}
  C_0 &\longrightarrow \mathbf{P}^{h+1}\\
  (x,y) &\longmapsto (1:x:x^2:\cdots:x^h:y)
\end{aligned}$$
where $h = \lceil d/2 \rceil$. Then, $\overline{C} \cap \{z_0 \ne 0\} \cong C_0$ and $\overline{C} \cap \{z_0 \ne 0\} \cong C_\infty$, where $C_\infty = \{v^2 = \prod(1-a_iu)\}$ and $z_i$ are the coordinates on $\mathbf{P}^{h+1}$.